# Database Select statment not tatking input from html input field

Tags: mariadb, centos

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/home/will/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()
> File "/home/will/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
> File "/home/will/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.dispatch_request()
> File "/home/will/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
> return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
> File "main.py", line 30, in do_admin_login
> conn.execute(query)
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [ma-3.1.12][10.3.28-MariaDB]Unknown column 'tvandiver' in 'where clause' (1054) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Error I get when executing login prompt. tvandiver is what is entered into html page.
If I run a statement in sql console I get a back response of 1. When I run it with HTML page through python3 it sends back an error. I have tried wrapping input from the page in str() but still wont take the inputted text. Also if I run it just in python3 same SELECT statement it returns True, but not from html input field.

Answer (score 0):

You're suffering a self-inflicted **SQL Injection Attack**.

You're building your SQL as a [Python] string but not building the SQL literal for the username correctly.

Here's what I guess your SQL looks like:

```
select column1 from table2 where column3 = tvandiver
```

Try to execute this and the database tries to find the column "tvandiver" in the table.  Of course, it's not there - this is a data *value*, not a column name.

At the *very least*, you need to wrap this in [usually] single quotes, so that your database views it as a literal value:

```
select column1 from table2 where column3 = 'tvandiver'
```

However, this won't help when you start getting names like `O'Brien` coming through, because the embedded single quote in that value will break your SQL again!

```
select column1 from table2 where column3 = 'O'Brien'
```

/By far/ your best option is to look at Parameterised Queries (a.k.a. Prepared Statements).  Here, your SQL contains not literal values (with all these problems) but placeholders that are substituted as part of the execution.  I don't know Python, but here's some PHP code that demonstrates the idea:

```
$sql = 'select column1 from table2 where column3 = :name' ; 
$db->prepare( $sql ); 
$db->execute( [ 'name' => 'tvandiver' ] );
```

I assume that Python would have something very much like this.

Comment: # Getting Username and Password from HTML login page
    login = request.form
    uname = login['username']
    password = login['password']
    # Putting information though sql SELECT statement
    query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_name={} AND password={}".format(uname, password)     I have tired this and also calling values in .execute(query, (username, password))   format, but always get back error.

Comment: You are still not creating valid SQL.  Valid String?  Yes.  Valid SQL?  No.  
The format() method only replaces the {} placeholders with the given values, it does not wrap them in the /single quotes/ required to make valid *SQL* literals.  
[1] try something more like "SELECT ... WHERE user_name = '{}' ... ".format( ... )
[2] read up about parameterised queries (using the /database's/ way of doing much the same thing, only better). 
[3] STOP storing plain-text passwords and start storing a one-way hashed value based on the entered password (and compare against same).

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the single quote around the brackets. still returns error. pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query. I am going to read up on parameterised queries now.